# How to query a table which has a parent child relation

Tags: join, sql-server-2008-r2, relation

**Situation**:

I have a table called "word" which contains a word with the associated translations.

```
| ID | name     | lang_id | parent_id |
|----|----------|---------|-----------|
| 1  | screw    | 1       | null      |
| 2  | schraube | 2       | 1         |
| 3  | vis      | 3       | 1         |
```

So screw is the main word which has no parent. The other data sets have an association to the parent with the parent_id.

**What I want:**

I need a query which displays the word I searched for and the word which I typed in.

- I want to get the datasets 2 and 3, if I query the word "schraube" from german to french.
- I want to get the datasets 1 and 3, if I query the word "screw" from english to french.
- ...

**What I tried:**

```
select word.id, word.name, word.lang_id, word.parent_id
from word
left join word w2 on word.parent_id = w2.parent_id 
WHERE w2.name = 'screw';
-- and word.lang_id = 2
```

Unfortunately the result doesn't contain the word I typed. Also this displays all datasets, not only the ones with the specific language.

Comment: search for "recursive common table expression"

Answer (score 0):

You can modifiy  th below query to get  your answer.

```
DECLARE @FromLanguageId SMALLINT = 2; --german 
DECLARE @ToLanguageId SMALLINT = 3; --french 
DECLARE @NAME NVARCHAR(300) = 'schraube'; 

--DECLARE @FromLanguageId SMALLINT = 1;  --english 
--DECLARE @ToLanguageId SMALLINT = 3;   --french 
--DECLARE @NAME NVARCHAR(300) = 'screw'; 
--Get  the mathing record 
; 
WITH ctematch 
     AS ( 
        --gets the matching record (child or parent)
        SELECT match.* 
         FROM   [word] match 
         WHERE  match.NAME LIKE @NAME), 
     --Join its sibling , parent and childs 
     ctefamilydata 
     AS (SELECT * 
         FROM   ctematch match 
         UNION 
         --Parent 
         SELECT parent.* 
         FROM   ctematch match 
                INNER JOIN [word] parent 
                        ON match.[parent_id] = parent.[id] 
         UNION 
         --Child 
         SELECT child.* 
         FROM   ctematch match 
                INNER JOIN [word] child 
                        ON child.[parent_id] = match.[id] 
         UNION 
         --Siblings 
         SELECT siblings.* 
         FROM   ctematch match 
                INNER JOIN [word] siblings 
                        ON match.[parent_id] = siblings.[parent_id]) 
--Filter and get the data 
SELECT * 
FROM   ctefamilydata Cte 
WHERE  Cte.[lang_id] = @ToLanguageId 
        OR Cte.[lang_id] = @FromLanguageId
```